# In Powershell with Taglib#, how get xiph Rating value for Flac file?

Tags: powershell, taglib-sharp

OK, I have exhausted my (somewhat limited) abilities in Powershell to try to do this.  I am hoping someone can help.

I am happily using taglib-sharp for various tags - getting and setting - for Flac and MP3.  But, I cannot figure out how to get or set the RATING tag *value* that is stored in the xiph tags.

The closest I come is this:

```
$tags = [taglib.file]::create("d:\songs\ASong.flac")
$xiph = $tags.gettag("xiph")
```

$xiph then contains the list of tags but no values.  It's Powershell type is XiphComment.

Help?  Thanks

PS: I would also like to get the Rating value on MP3 so if the solution above isn't easily translatable for those please provide tips.  I currently retrieve Rating for MP3 through the Windows Shell namespace "GetDetailsOf" but would prefer to use taglib#.